# Setting up spherical coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fArUF.jpg

Why is $\theta$   between $\pi/2$ and $0$?
I thought it will be $0$ to $2\pi$ since the sphere will cover that whole axis (all the quadrants for XY-plane).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMe7v.jpg

How did they find the range for $\Phi$?

I understand $θ$ is between $3\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$ because y is both (+) and (-) and x is in the negative quadrants. But how did they come up with $\Phi$, is it because it only uses the ZY axis and never the ZX axis?

Comment: Inserting such untidy drafts is not appreciated here.